# Find the asymptotics of members of the series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f(n)=\frac{1}{n^2+1}+...+\frac{1}{n^2+n}$. Represent $f(n)$ as $f(n)=a+\frac{b}{n}+\frac{c}{n^2}+\frac{d}{n^3}+o(\frac{1}{n^3})$.

Using limits I found that $$a=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=0$$ and $$b=\lim_{n\to\infty}nf(n)=1$$
I cant found other coefficients. I tried to found $c$ as $$c=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2(f(n)-\frac{1}{n})$$ but i couldn't found the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n^2+k}=\int_0^n\frac{\mathrm dx}{n^2+x}+\frac12\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{n^2}\right)+\mathcal O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)$$

The integral is given by

$$\int_0^n\frac{\mathrm dx}{n^2+x}=\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{kn^k}=\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{3n^3}+\mathcal O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)$$

and we have by geometric series

$$\frac1{n+1}=\frac1n\frac1{1+\frac1n}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{n^k}=\frac1n-\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{n^3}+\mathcal O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)$$

which gives us the asymptotic expansion:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n^2+k}=\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}-\frac1{6n^3}+\mathcal O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$n^2(f(n)-{1\over n}){=n^2(f(n)-{n\over n^2})\\=-n^2\sum_{i=1}^n{i\over n^2(n^2+i)}\\=-\sum_{i=1}^n{i\over n^2+i}}$$